# Delete topic from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code that allows a user to only delete his own topics. It's working but in the case that the user is not the one who posted the topic, he is still getting the message: Topic has been deleted, whereas he should get: You didnt make this topic.
The else statement isnt running.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid']; 
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = '$id' AND topicCreator = '$uid'");
    if($check){
        $query1=mysql_query("delete FROM topics WHERE id='$id' AND topicCreator='$uid'");
        echo "<p>Topic has been successfully deleted. <a href='index.php'>Click here to return to home page.</a>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p><b>ERROR: You didnt make this topic.";
    }
}
```

I dont know why the else statement wont run.

$check is to see if the user who is logged in is the one who created the topic.

(PS: I'll switch to mysqli once this works.)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: `$check` is an object. It will always be truthy even if the query returns nothing.

Comment: The variable `$check` will be a result resource, hence it will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Then what should I do to make it false?

Comment: Need to use a `mysql_fetch_*` type of function to have it provide you the results from the resource.

Comment: Ok thanks it worked. I did if(mysql_fetch_assoc($check))

Comment: Great I added an answer that might be more helpful for you too.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, you can't check against the resource itself. Try:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $uid = $_SESSION['uid']; 
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id = '$id' AND topicCreator = '$uid'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($check);
    if($count) {
        // $count is greater than 1 hence TRUE
        $query1=mysql_query("delete FROM topics WHERE id='$id' AND topicCreator='$uid'");
        echo "<p>Topic has been successfully deleted. <a href='index.php'>Click here to return to home page.</a>";
    } else{
        // $count is 0 or FALSE - no rows returned
        echo "<p><b>ERROR: You didnt make this topic.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working, just changed if($check) to if(mysql_fetch_assoc($check))